# SonataAdminBundle complains about missing "position"

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm trying to upgrade an old project from SonataAdminBundle 2.2 to 2.3
Navigating the dashboard looks fine, but in my functional tests I'm getting the following exception:

```
Key "position" does not exist as the array is empty in SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig at line 23
```

The following stack trace goes inside cached twig templates, so it doesn't help.

Comment: Is there `position` in one of your config files?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you still have old template from 2.2 vesion

Look it is dashboard template from 2.2 https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/2.2/Resources/views/Core/dashboard.html.twig#L23 that really has "position" key of variable "block"

But if you will look to 2.3 https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/2.3/Resources/views/Core/dashboard.html.twig
You won't see "position" key at all

So I suppose the answer is how do you "trying to upgrade" and seems you still have old stuff from 2.2

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a simple cache learing wasn't enough. I manually deleted all files in my cache and tried again, now it works. Thanks everyone